# Determine the interval of convergence for the following power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

A need in help... in full I guess?

Determine the interval of convergence for the following power series

(a)  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{csch}(n)x^n$$
(b)  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigg(\arctan \bigg({1\over \sqrt{n}}\bigg)\bigg)x^n$$
Qustion (a) need to be fixed because I don't know how to write hyperbolic csc.

Comment: Have you tried something ? What are the theorems you know ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

a. For large $n$, $\text{csch }n$ is essentially $e^{-n}$, hence radius $e$, $\pm e$ excluded.

b. For large $n$, $\arctan\dfrac1{\sqrt n}$ is essentially $\dfrac1{\sqrt n}$, hence radius $1$, $+1$ excluded.

Answer (score -1):

- $a_n=\dfrac{2}{e^n-\frac{1}{e^n}}=\dfrac{2e^n}{e^{2n}-1}$

Consider $\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=e^{-1}\times\dfrac{e^{2(n+1)}-1}{e^{2n}-1}=e^{-1}\times\dfrac{(e-\frac{1}{e^n})(e+\frac{1}{e^n})}{(1-\frac{1}{e^n})(1+\frac{1}{e^n})}=e$ as $n\to \infty$

So $R=e$

- $a_n=\tan^{-1}(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n})$

Note that $\tan^{-1}(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n})<\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}$

so $a_n^{\frac{1}{n}}=(\tan^{-1}(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n}))^{\frac{1}{n}}<(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n})^{\frac{1}{n}}$

$(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt n})^{\frac{1}{n}}=(\dfrac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}})^{\frac{1}{2}}\to 1$

Hence $R=1$

Comment: Your solution for b) is wrong.